# Make two fieldsets the same height

Tags: html, css

I have two `<fieldset>`s inside a single div (nothing else), that are positioned next to eachother (positon: absolute, div is set to relative).

Is there any way to make these fieldsets both the same height without setting a fixed height?

I have some idea that maybe I can make both have a max height of the parent, and a min height of auto?

Also, would it then be possible to make the content of the fieldsets position centred vertically?

I'm not concerned if it works with IE, but needs to work on Firefox and Webkit, and if possible Opera.

Thanks

Edit: You can see the page here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2318402/SO/login.html

Comment: Check @Luis Css sample:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10906526/1514062

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put them in a parent container like a table or div, and have the two children be at `height=100%`.

The only other two options are the ones you didn't want, at a fixed height like `height=59px`, or you can do it via javascript.

For the vertical positioning, you can stick them in a parent container like a table or div and then slap on there a `vertical-align:center`

Comment: Neither of these worked; height:100%; made the boxes shorter than they were, and vertical-align:center changed nothing. Here's the content of the page, if it helps: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2318402/SO/login.html Thanks

Comment: vertical-align: center will not do what you want it to do. http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be a suitable solution, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late but you can always use tables (don't like those either but well.. table works in this situation).

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align:top">
           <fieldset></fieldset>   
      </td>   
      <td style="vertical-align:top">
           <fieldset></fieldset>   
      </td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works, without using js/jQuery, but does rely on -in this example- using a css3 psuedo-element [`:nth-of-type(odd)`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype), though this could be replaced by applying a css class to the odd-numbered fieldsets.

It also relies on using `height: 100%` for the `fieldset`s, which itself is dependant upon the parent element (in this case the `form`) having a specified height. If that's a problem then, for the purpose of demonstration, I've used `overflow-y: auto;` on the fieldsets to restrict their dimensions to that of their parent, but with a scroll behaviour to reveal the overflow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/mindez/css/stylesheet.css" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

        form        {
                width: 50%;
                height: 200px;
                }

        fieldset    {
                width: 30%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0 1em 0 0;
                padding: 0.5em 1em;
                overflow-y: auto;
                }

        fieldset:nth-of-type(odd)
                {
                float: left;
                }

        label       {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 30%;
                }

        input[type=text]
                {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 50%;
                }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrap">

        <form enctype="form/multipart" method="post" action="">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="one">Label 1</label><input id="one" name="one" type="text" />
                <label for="two">Label 2</label><input id="two" name="two" type="text" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <label for="three">Label 3</label><input id="three" name="three" type="text" />
                <label for="four">Label 4</label><input id="four" name="four" type="text" />
                <label for="five">Label 5</label><input id="five" name="five" type="text" />
                <label for="six">Label 6</label><input id="six" name="six" type="text" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Demo online at: http://www.davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/fieldsets.html.

Obviously, if there's any questions or problems feel free to raise them in the comments and I'll try my best to help you out. =)

Comment: You're using a fixed height? I'd like to avoid doing that

Comment: @Jeffrey Aylesworth, unfortunately for a child element to have a height measured in percent (the least restrictive way of ensuring siblings have equal height) the parent's height has to be specified. You could use JS to make the specified height more dynamic, though.