# Fieldset height 100% of its parent

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `fieldsets` wrapped in a `<div>`, let's call them `blah1` and `blah2`.

`blah2` can grow as the max of its `<div>` parent, but I need `blah1` to have the same % height of his sibling `blah2`

[This is my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/nGCdx/7/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer was kinda weird, but I make it work, looks like the margin was making a mess here, if I set it to `margin: 0 5px;` then I can make both `fieldsets` to have the same `height` as their parent

Part of the **css** markup:

```
fieldset
{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 100%;
}

legend
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.blahContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.blahColumna1{
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you wanna see the final demo, [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/nGCdx/13/).

Hope it can help somebody else...

Comment: Works in Chrome, but not IE10.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping both `<fieldset>`s in a single container `<div>` that isn't fixed height -- it will neatly enclose `blah2`, and will grow up to the max size of your `<div>` parent. Set `blah1`'s height to be 100% of the containing `<div>`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, maybe I'm doing something wrong, could you update my demo so I can understand you better? thx

Comment: Best I could do is http://jsfiddle.net/nGCdx/8/ -- needed to give the container a height to get it to work. I gave it an arbitrarily small value.

Comment: Looks like a good option while I find a way to make it exactly what I need, thx for the effort

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by adding `padding-bottom` to the fieldset for Chrome only.  This balances out some of the extra height %.  It's nice in that it works (relatively consistently) even when resizing.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome')) { // Replace this with your preferred way of checking userAgent
    $('fieldset').css('padding-bottom', '4%'); // Exact percent may vary
}
```

Just as a note, I found this to be an issue in at least IE8 - IE11 as well, so the fix can be applied to IE.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10906526/2895480) in 2024 and in google chrome, and they are no longer working properly as can be confirmed in the various jsfiddle demos. It appears that the solution is now to do something like:

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr; width: 100%">
      <div style="height: 100%">
        <fieldset  style="height: calc(100% - 19px)">
          <legend>Field Set 1:</legend>
          a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div style="height: 100%">
        <fieldset  style="height: calc(100% - 19px)">
          <legend>Field Set 2:</legend>
          b<br/>b<br/>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
</div>
```

The key seems to be the `calc(100% - 19px)`, where the 19 is actually some function of the padding, border thickness, radius and possibly margin. Someone who cares more than me can figure out exactly what this calculation needs to be for pixel perfection in all circumstances.